# Create column to populate match from other columns

Tags: r, match

I have what I think is a simple Match, but can't quite get it to work. For the example dataframe below, I would like to add a column that returns the value of the column number. Eg: for row #1, the value of x should equal 4, row #2, the value should equal 3, etc.

```
# create sample data frame
    c1 <- c("1","2","3")
    c2 <- c("8","1","3")
    c3 <- c("4","2","4")
    c4 <- c("1","3","5")
    df <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4)
    colnames(df)[c(1:4)] <- c("CodeToMatch","Code.1","Code.2","Code.3")
    View(df)

    df <- as.data.frame(df)

# my attempt create a column at the end which populates the column location of "CodeToMatch"
    df$x <- match(df$CodeToMatch,2:4)
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are matching to the *numbers* 2:4 instead of to those *columns* of the data frame. In addition, you don't do the matching row wise. This should work:

```
df$x <- apply(df, 1, function(row) match(row[1], row[2:4])) + 1
```

Note that 1 is added to each match at the end, because column 1 was not included for the matching.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you made all columns of `df` `factor`s; it would be more sensible to have them as `numeric` vectors. That aside, here is one option using `which`

```
# Convert factors to numeric
df[] <- Map(function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)), df)

# Find column indices of matching entries
df$x <- 1 + mapply(function(x, y) which(x == y), df[, 1], as.data.frame(t(df[, -1])))
#  CodeToMatch Code.1 Code.2 Code.3 x
#1           1      8      4      1 4
#2           2      1      2      3 3
#3           3      3      4      5 2
```

Actually, since you're doing a row-wise operation, there is nothing wrong here with a good old `for` loop with pre-allocation; this should be as fast as the other `*apply` solutions.

```
# Convert factors to numeric
df[] <- Map(function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)), df)

df$x <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) df$x[i] <- which(df[i, 1] == df[i, -1]) + 1
#  CodeToMatch Code.1 Code.2 Code.3 x
#1           1      8      4      1 4
#2           2      1      2      3 3
#3           3      3      4      5 2
```